# Integral of trigonometric function using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'd like to get some feedback on the following calculation:

$$\int{\frac{(\cos{\frac{1}{x}})^2}{x^2}}\,\,dx$$

Using substitution, let

$$u = \frac{1}{x},\,\,\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2},\,\,du = -\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$

So

$$\int{\frac{(\cos{\frac{1}{x}})^2}{x^2}}\,\,dx = -\int{(\cos{u})^2}\,\,du = -\int{\cos^2{u}}\,\,du$$

Using trigonometric identities for $\cos^2{u}$, we find the integral:

$$-\int{\cos^2{u}}\,\,du = -(\frac{u}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin2{u}) + c$$

$$= -\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{4}\sin{\frac{2}{x}}+c$$

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. If you don't want use the trigonometric formulas I suggest you use the integration by parts. In this way:
$$\int \cos^2 u du= \int\cos u \cos u du=\int \cos u (\sin u)' du$$

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the input.